# Android Studio 0.8.1: New project and can't preview the L version in the renderer of phones

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-theme, android-5.0-lollipop

I installed Api level 20 and 19 after installing 0.8.1 and created a brand new project. But in the renderer (preview) of an activity.xml I don't see the right L version rendered. I see the API L on the drop down which is selected but the phone looks like the HALO effect even on L.

Before installing the level 20 and 19 it did seem to work. But a new project now creates the following gradle file and there is v21 theme; it is always set to

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Before installing 19 and 20, I noticed a values-v21 directory but it never creates it now.

Here is a copy of my gradle that gets created. I have tried playing around with these values but it doesn't work.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tester.myapplicationtest"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
```

The strange thing is before installing api 19 and 20 I think it was working.

On New Project it never asks me for the sdk or max version just a min version which I leave at 15.

The reason I downloaded api 20 and 19 was that when I am building a production app I presume that this is a better api to build against due to the nature of L preview (beta). However, I didn't realize it was going to stop creating the correct Android new project template.

Answer (score 1):

You have to manually set the compile target to L-preview. Go to File->Project Structure, select your module, under the tab "Properties" there is a "Compile Sdk Version". Change to "android-L". Make sure you have updated the latest build tools(version 20) too.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem too. I had installed API 20, 19, 15 and 10 but Android Studio was not rendering the .XML file. Sometimes Android Studio never generated .java and .XML files too.

I figured out that having any versions of Eclipse (Kepler, Juno or ADT) on the same computer made Android Studio not to work properly and show rendering problems.

**The solution to this is to delete the eclipse installation which you are using and .eclipse folder in C:\users\user-name\ and later run Android Studio. You can install Eclipse once Android Studio works. Both Android Studio and Eclipse runs fine now.**